# Implement a function using Boolean Circuit

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, truthtable

I need to implement some multi-variable function in a Boolean Circuit; what tools do we have in order to automatically convert some arithmetics into a boolean circuit?

For instance, part of the formula I want to implement is the operator `max(a,b)` that gets 2 numbers (16 bits for now) and returns the index of the maximal number (i.e. 0 or 1).

I know that I can build the truth table and convert it into a boolean circuit automatically but that would require a really huge circuit (there are 2^32 entries).

Answer (score 1):

you can use Quartus II web pack addition, In which you have to describe hardware behaviour, and that tool will generate RTL at gate level for you,

Behaviour is written like,

```
if (a>b)
  index = 0;
else 
  index = 1:
```

Then run and see RTL View, it can be done only you know Verilog HDL and Quartus II.